# Conditional template if milliseconds are 000 or not in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-template

I'm building a conditional template for my Kendo Scatter Chart, in which the y axis is a values axis and the x axis is the timestamp axis.

The tooltip that shows the value should also display the timestamp all the way until the milliseconds but it should be conditional: if the milliseconds are 000, I don't want to display them.

Example:
// If not 000

24/08/2016 - 14:22:15:313

// If 000

24/08/2016 - 14:21:54

My difficulty is in evaluating the current value ({0}, value.x) and then comparing it to '000'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the x-axis is already a date you don't need the `new Date` or the `Date.parse`. If it is a string, then you only need one of those.

I find it easier to use a function for the template instead of  the formatted string:

```
template: function(dataItem) {
    var tt = "<li style='text-align: left;'>Date: ";
     if (dataItem.value.x.getMilliseconds() > 0){
         tt += kendo.toString(dataItem.value.x, "dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss:fff");
     } else {
         tt += kendo.toString(dataItem.value.x, "dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss");;
     }
     tt += "</li><li style='text-align: left;'>Value: ";
     tt += dataItem.value.y;
     tt += "</li>";
     return tt;
 }
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/yJmNvO)**

Comment: Thanks that was exactly it. (Also: I was writting milliseconds in my json file with ":" instead of ".").